# how to set an array value in local.settings.json file in azure functions

Tags: c#, azure

When I try to insert an array as one of the Values in **local.settings.json** file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "myArray": [
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      },
      {
        "key1": "value3",
        "key2": "value4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "myConnectionString"
  }
}
```

I start getting exceptions. Can arrays be used in the `local.settings.json` file? And if they can, what's the correct format?

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the array indexer format.

E.g.

```
"myArray:[0]:key1": "value1",
"myArray:[0]:key2": "value2",
"myArray:[1]:key1": "value3",
"myArray:[1]:key2": "value4"
```

Comment: It does for me! I have been using this successfully on an azure function v3 project. Version 3 libs of Microsoft.Extension packages

Comment: This definitely does work! I've just hooked it up myself, thanks to @Umair. I've expanded on exactly what I did to get it working in a separate answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to set an array in the local.settings.json file / environment variables, you can specify the following format:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyArray:0:Name": "Test",
    "MyArray:1:Name": "Test2",
    "MyArray:2:Name": "Test3"
  }
}
```

In Startup.cs you can use the following syntax to bind the array

```
var settings = new List<MyArrayType>();
configuration.GetSection("MyArray").Bind(settings);
```

This is an example with .NET 6.0 and Azure Functions v4

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible!

My local settings file looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "CustomArray": [
    {
      "CustomProp1": "foo0",
      "CustomProp2": "bar0"
    },
    {
      "CustomProp1": "foo1",
      "CustomProp2": "bar1"
    }
  ]
}
```

My config when deployed to Azure looks like this:
[image: Azure Function Settings Screenshot]

Then, to resolve the array in my Startup, I have something like this:

```
var settings = new List<CustomSetting>();
config.GetSection("CustomArray").Bind(settings);
```

... where `CustomSetting` is a class like this:

```
public class CustomSetting 
{
    public string CustomProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am using version 3.1.5 of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` Nuget package, and version 3.0.7 of the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` Azure Functions SDK.

Comment: Is that possible to define the `CustomArray` in Azure by this way?

Comment: @Wladyslaw - yes. There's a screenshot in the answer above, showing how I set up my config in Azure to work the same as local.settings.json.

Comment: I'm blind... Thanks! That makes sense!

Comment: I have to notice that Linux VM doesn't support the symbols like `:`, `[]`

Comment: This simply **does not work**. `Configuration.GetSection(sectionName).Exists()` returns `false` if the specified section does not exist under the `Values` node in `local.settings.json`, and of course attempting to `Bind()` to a nonexistent section does not work.

Comment: This does not work as Ian Kemp mentioned.

Comment: Can't get it to work either, @NeilD can you provide more specific instructions?

Comment: Most definitely did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Add the array like string in local.settings.json file:

```
"myArray": "[
             {
               \"key1\": \"value1\",
               \"key2\": \"value2\"
             },
             {
               \"key1\": \"value3\",
               \"key2\": \"value4\"
             }
            ]"
```

Then deserialize it in your code as below:

```
string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myArray");

objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(value);
```

Comment: When using suggested method and starting local azure function console, I keep getting that it can't determine the language being used. Once I remove the above from the local.settings.json, the application works again as expected

Answer (score 3):

> Can arrays be used in the local.settings.json file? And if they can, what's the correct format?

It seems that **arrarys** is not supported currently in the local.settings.json.

As far as I know Values collection is expected to be a **Dictionary**, if it contains any **non-string** values, it will cause Azure function can not read values from local.settings.json

Based on my test, if it contains it will return **null** value

```
 "myArray": [
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      },
      {
        "key1": "value3",
        "key2": "value4"
      }
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this without making it complex you can simply create an array as follows which works perfectly inside the local.settings.json file in Azure Functions -

```
"myArray": "[\"Value1\",\"Value2\"]"
```

Comment: You will get a string of strings like this "[\"Value1\",\"Value2\"]", how will you convert this into a list of string values? I am sure that you can use a delimiter but how do we make sure we pick the right delimiter? Let's say you pick comma as the delimiter in this case, how do we make sure there is no comma in the values? Or we have to rule that you need to use | instead of ,? Anyway, I think this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are already a couple of good answers here for simple arrays, but wanted to add a couple of details related to complex objects in case somebody comes across this needing a "full example" with an array that contains nested objects.
In short, arrays can be referenced like below. The following is an array for 2 Leases with a simple string "Name" property. Additionally, the array index appears to work with or without the brackets. I'm adding the brackets because it makes it more clear that this is an array item.

```
"Values": {
    "Leases:[0]:Name": "Lease1",
    "Leases:[1]:Name": "Lease2"
}
```

But in my case, I also had complex nested config objects, not just simple primitives. The convention for this is double underscores between the object and it's properties, and they can be nested multiple levels deep. For example, I have an array of Lease objects, each with a complex RateLimit property which in turn has a complex FixedWindow property like so:

```
public class LeaseOptions
{
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public RateLimitOptions? RateLimit { get; init; }
}

public class RateLimitOptions
{
    public int PermitLimit { get; init; } = 10;
    public FixedWindowOptions? FixedWindow { get; init; }
}

public class FixedWindowOptions
{
    public int PermitLimit { get; init; }
    public TimeSpan Window { get; init; }
}
```

And my config looks like this:

```
"Values": {
    "Leases:[0]:Name": "Lease1",
    "Leases:[0]:RateLimit__PermitLimit": 10,
    "Leases:[0]:RateLimit__FixedWindow__PermitLimit": 500,
    "Leases:[0]:RateLimit__FixedWindow__Window": "0:0:1:0",
    "Leases:[1]:Name": "Lease2",
    "Leases:[1]:RateLimit__PermitLimit": 1
    "Leases:[1]:RateLimit__FixedWindow__PermitLimit": 100,
    "Leases:[2]:RateLimit__FixedWindow__Window": "0:0:5:0"
}
```

Loading the config is as easy as binding a basic list from config:

```
 var leaseOptions = new List<LeaseOptions>();
 configuration.GetSection("Leases").Bind(leaseOptions);
```