# I can no longer get the values from local.setting.json with Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, environment-variables, azure-functions

I was able to get and use the values from local.setting.json using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test1");`
now it's like there is no way to get this file and his values. I only know that another developer that isn't in my team changed something and from then doesn't works anymore... (I can't understand what he changes that can be the problem)

Actually for testing I tried this:

```
var appSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();

var b = appSettings["test1"];
var c = appSettings["test2"];

var d = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
var e = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
var f = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
var g = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test1");
```

After this all the variables are null

The local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "test1": "abcd",
    "test2": "efgh"
   }
 }
```

I'm using visual studio 2017 and the project is Azure Functions, the file local.settings.json it's at the same level of the function.cs.

What could be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
             .Build();
```

It may be the case that your context.FunctionAppDirectory may be incorrect. Please also right click the config file -> Configuration -> Advanced => set Copy to output directory to Copy If Newer.

Comment: Im having this same issue, but this solution doesnt make it for me. I have verified that my local.settings.json is being copied to my output directory also. I have used `context.FunctionAppDirectory` and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` but my values dont appear as environment variables
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677093/azure-functions-settings-not-consistent-betwen-portal-and-local/56678921#56678921

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the contents of the `local.settings.json` are read by the `IConfigurationBuilder` however, for some reason they're not loaded on the Environment variables list `(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())` so the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` will never read them. So I'm in my Startup class, I manually attached the variables to the current process.

Here's my local.settings.json

```
{
  "Values" : { "Region": "southeastasia" }
}
```

In my Startup class, here's my `IConfigurationRoot`:

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
```

And here's how I attached them to the process:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Region", configuration.GetValue<string>("Values:Region"), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Now your `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` should look like this:

```
string region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Region", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was attempting to create a list in local.settings.json e.g:

```
array1: [
  "value1",
  "value2"
]
```

Which is not supported, fix to issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025999/how-to-set-an-array-value-in-local-settings-json-file-in-azure-functions)

```
"array1:0":"value1",
"array1:1":"value2",
```