# Azure Functions settings not consistent betwen portal and local

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Im working with Azure functions and have a problem. 
I declared a `local.settings.json` file with my variables as follows:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "TopicEndpoint": "my endpoint"
  }  
}
```

This allows my azure function to read the settings using:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
var myTopic = config["Values:TopicEndpoint"];
```

This allows me to publish and export my variables to the portal via:

`func azure functionapp
publish myfunctionapp --publish-local-settings -i`

However, upon publishing and verifying that the value is in the 'Application Settings' in the portal, the "Values:TopicEndpoint" doesn't exist.

In order to be able to access its value i have to put my variables directly under the json root:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
  }  
  "TopicEndpoint": "my endpoint"
}
```

That way I can safely use `config['TopicEndpoint']` both in my local development environment, as well as on Azure. However, this defeats the purpose of the `--publish-local-settings -i` as it only exports the values found under the 'Values' key, so I have to create all my settings manually.

Do you know why this happens or if maybe Im missing something?

Comment: When you are deploying, did it show `App setting AzureWebJobsStorage is different between azure and local.settings.json
Would you like to overwrite value in azure? [yes/no/show]`?

Comment: No it didnt show that warning during deploy, but im positive that the values on the portal got updated when they were declared inside the Values key.

Comment: Maybe you could have a try `--overwrite-settings [-y]` with `--publish-local-settings -i`. And what do you mean the values on the portal got updated when they were declared inside the Values key? You said before the `Values:TopicEndpoint` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure it doesnt exist. It gets updated as an application setting which can only be read by doing config["TopicEndpoint"] and its not inside the 'Values' key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.
The problem was that I was adding a separate secret.settings.json as suggested here 
https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-local-settings-json-and-source-control/
Therefore I was loading my configurations like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

My local settings file looked like this:

```
{
  "Values": {
      "TopicEndpoint": "my endpoint"
  }  
}
```

And my secret settings like this:

```
{
  "Values": {
      "TopicKey": "my key"
  }  
}
```

This caused a conflict so I needed to remove the 'Values' key from the secret.settings.json so that it looked like this:

```
{
  "TopicKey": "my key"
}
```

This way I am able to both use `func azure functionapp publish myfunctionapp --publish-local-settings -i` to deploy the values inside my local settings file and use both files as environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use it a bit in a different way it should be. The thing is that the values from the `local.settings.json` [come as environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables) automatically, so you don't have to worry about working with the file at all. That's how we do it on our project and it works on all environments.

```
// see, just env variables
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

// and then use
var value = configuration["TopicEndpoint"];
```

Comment: I have taken a look at the documentation and agree with your approach. However I have added my keys inside the "Values" but I dont see them added as environment variables, might this be a known issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue at all, that's how we do it on our project. Have you tried the code I've posted?