# Azure Functions - Adding array of settings?

Tags: azure-functions, settings

So my Azure Function locally reads an array of settings and performs some logic on each object.
My `local.settings.json` is below.

I could add the singular `Settings` keys in the Portal settings, but what is the best way to add arrays such as `projects`? Can I simply include another JSON file in my project? Silly question probably, but haven't found an answer so far.

```
{
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "..."
  },
  "Settings": {
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/myproject",
    "genericProjectName": "myproject",
    "genericWikiName": "myproject.wiki",
    "projects": [
      {
        "parentPagePath": "/Release notes",
        "name": "Project 1",
        "wikiName": "Project-1.wiki",
        "leasing": true
      }
      {
        "parentPagePath": "/Release notes",
        "name": "Project-2",
        "wikiName": "Project-2.wiki",
        "leasing": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this is impossible. This is by design.

Comment: However, you can deploy your own json file to Azure, and then process it yourself. You can look at the answer I wrote.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72136305/1037864

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set an array value in local.settings.json file in azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025999/how-to-set-an-array-value-in-local-settings-json-file-in-azure-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, adding arrays is not possible. The reason is because of the implementation of the source code that reads the local.settings.json file into environment variables. The specific implementation is listed below:

```
        public AppSettingsFile(string filePath)
        {
            _filePath = filePath;
            try
            {
                var content = FileSystemHelpers.ReadAllTextFromFile(_filePath);
                var appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettingsFile>(content);
                IsEncrypted = appSettings.IsEncrypted;
                Values = appSettings.Values;
                ConnectionStrings = appSettings.ConnectionStrings;
                Host = appSettings.Host;
            }
            catch
            {
                Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                ConnectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                IsEncrypted = true;
            }
        }

        public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

For detailed code, please check this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/653796ce5d0b5ae9bfd9ecf4073ea1cd010f295e/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Common/SecretsManager.cs

You can find that Setting and Connecting String are the directory types from the beginning of the design. It does not support array.

So, you have two ways to attach your goal.

**First way,** change the structure.

```
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "...",
    "projects1-parentPagePath": "/Release notes",
    "projects1-name": "Project 1",
    "projects1-wikiName": "Project-1.wiki",
    "projects1-leasing": true,
    "projects2-parentPagePath": "/Release notes",
    "projects2-name": "Project-2",
    "projects2-wikiName": "Project-2.wiki",
    "projects2-leasing": true
  }
```

**Second way,** design your own code.

You can create your own json file and fill in the code you want. Then change the copy property in its property to copy if newer.

Then you can design your own code to read the information of the json file. Here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpTrigger
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        public static string GetFileJson(string filepath)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
                {
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                }
            }
            return json;
        }
        //Read Json Value
        public static string ReadJson()
        {
            string jsonfile = "custom.json";
            string jsonText = GetFileJson(jsonfile);
            JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
            string value = ((JObject)jsonObj["Settings"])["projects"]["parentPagePath"].ToString();
            return value;
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string value = ReadJson();

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this soon and accept your answer when I get it working. :)