# Azure webjob using .NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I am writing a azure webjob using .net core 3.1 and I am getting the following runtime exception:
InvalidOperationException: %EventHubName% does not resolve to a value.

where my trigger looks like: 

`ProcessEvent([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData eventData)`

I have registered the configuration in program.cs

I have added appSettings.environment.json file which contains something like:

`"EventHubConfig": {
    "EventHubConnectionString": "..",
    "EventHubName": "..",
    "EventProcessorHostName": "..",
    "ConsumerGroupName": "..",
    "StorageConnectionString": "..",
    "StorageContainerName": ".."
  },`

Can anyone suggest what I maybe missing?

Comment: Missing environment variable (or key/value in web.config)?

Comment: From where do you expect the "%EventHubName%"? Or what is the the event hub name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 0515:**

The workaround:

1.Please add both `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.dev.json`(Remember right click these files -> select properties -> set "Copy to Output Directory" as "copy if newer") files into your project. The 2 json files should have the same structure(the keys), but the value can be different. Like below:

My appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxxx",
  "EventHubConnectionString": "xxxx",
  "EventHubName": "yyeventhub1",
  "ConsumerGroupName": "cg1"
}
```

My appsettings.dev.json file:

```
   {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxxx",
      "EventHubConnectionString": "xxxx",
      "EventHubName": "yyeventhub2",
      "ConsumerGroupName": "hub2cg"
    }
```

2.In **CustomNameResolver** class, use the code below:

```
public class CustomNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.dev.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        return config[name];
    }
}
```

**note**, appsettings.json should be added before appsettings.dev.json, so the settings in appsettings.dev.json has high priority which will overwrite the same keys in appsettings.json.

3.Then run the project and send events to **yyeventhub2** which is defined in appsettings.dev.json, then you can find the webjob is triggered.

---

**Original answer:**

There're some limitations when use `%%` in the function.

As per my test, here are some notes:

1.Some latest nuget packages cannot work with eventhub trigger, you should use the below version of nuget packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

2.The eventhub namespace connection string cannot be used in this format `%EventHubConnectionString%` in the Functions.cs.

3.Don't use the nested settings in appsettings.json.

4.Don't specify `EventProcessorHostName` and `StorageContainerName` in appsettings.json. The webjobs SDK automatically set them for you.

5.When use %% format, you should use [Custom binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#custom-binding-expressions) to resolve the name.

The following are my code and appsettings.json:

**appsettings.json**(please also right click this file -> select Properties -> set "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy if newer"):

```
{     
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xx;BlobEndpoint=https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xxx.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xxx.file.core.windows.net/",
    "EventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxx",
    "EventHubName": "xxx",
    "ConsumerGroupName": "xxx"  
}
```

**My NameResolver class(create a custom class named CustomNameResolver.cs)**:

```
public class CustomNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        return config[name];
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
class Program
{     

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        var resolver = new CustomNameResolver();

        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
            b.AddEventHubs();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });          

        builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(resolver));

        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs:**

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessEvent([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString",ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData eventData, ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("it is triggered!" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Thanks a lot; but I get the same error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString')

Comment: fail: Host.Startup[0]
      Error indexing method 'WebhookEventsProcessorTriggerFunction'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException: Error indexing method 'WebhookEventsProcessorTriggerFunction'
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString')
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubOptions.AddReceiver(String eventHubName, String receiverConnectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.TryCreateAsync(TriggerBindingProviderContext context)

Comment: Created another project just like you suggested and that works. Not sure why mine is not working. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: if I remove appsettings.json file and just add appsettings.dev.json, it doesnt work! Looks like it is always expecting this file? Any workaround for that?

Comment: please confirm regarding appsettings.dev.json; this is a big blocker for me

Comment: @NandiniSinghal, yes, I can repro the issue. Update the answer with a workaround. If we want to find the root cause, it may take some times to investigate the source code of webjobs. Please let me know if you still have more issues:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `%%XXX%%` is the correct way to read settings.

When you are developing locally your app search for those variable in the `local.settings.json` file.

Example :

```
{
    "EventHubName": "myeventhubname"
}
```

If you deployed on Azure you need to add variables to the Applications Settings [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)

Comment: I have added the EventHubName config to settings file but in a nested json. How can I make it access the nested json?

Comment: do you mean that you added them under Values property ? if yes it should work !

Comment: yes, added a JSON in appsettings as in the question

Comment: can you check if this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057884/8288848 or you need to share with us some example of what you have in your appsettings json file.