# How to fix "No event hub receiver named <name>"

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I am writing an azure webjob which reads events from eventhub using NET Core 3.1.
I have a config file as below:

```
{
  "JobHostConfig": {
    "DashboardConnectionString": "",
    "StorageConnectionString": "xx"
  },
  "EventHubConfig": {
    "EventHubConnectionString": "xx",
    "EventHubName": "xx",
    "EventProcessorHostName": "xx",
    "ConsumerGroupName": "xx",
    "StorageConnectionString": "xx",
    "StorageContainerName": "xx"
  }
}
```

In the Main method, I call ConfigureServices method which looks something like:

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"\\..\\..\\..\\ConfigFiles")
            .AddJsonFile($"applicationConfig.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"applicationConfig.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.AddEnvironmentVariables()
                               .Build();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddMvcCore();
        services.AddSingleton(GetInstance<EventHubConfig>());
        services.AddSingleton(GetInstance<JobHostConfig>());
```

I confirmed that at runtime configs are getting populated in `Configuration` only like this: `Configuration["EventHubConfig:EventHubName"]`. But I also debugged that environment variables have not been set and its value is `null`.

So when I do:
`ProcessEvent([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%", Connection = "%ConnectionString%")] EventData eventData)` I get that `%EventHubName%` is not resolved.

Also, when I hard-code the values of these then I get: No event hub receiver named.

Can someone suggest what is wrong with my registration?

Furthermore, I replaced the values with string in EventHubTrigger, and I get Value cannot be null. Parameter name: receiverConnectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `%%` format, you should use [Custom binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#custom-binding-expressions).

For more details, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794569/10185816).

Please let me know if you still have more issues about it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the **`appsettings.json`** **`file -> click propertities -> set the "Copy to output directory"`** to "copy if newer"

and the code should be

```
public static void Trigger([EventHubTrigger("my eventhub name",Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData message, ILogger logger)
{

    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    Console.WriteLine(data+";;xxx");
}
```

Make your appsettings.json simpler like

```
{  
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", 
  "EventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xxxx"
}
```

Comment: Tried, still the same:  %EventHubConnectionString% does not resolve to a value

Comment: And if I manually set Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("EventHubConnectionString", "") then I get this error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString')

Comment: try with the above appsettings.json