# Durable Functions Error: Can't determine project language from files

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using durable function to setup a process where I am calling 6 functions at once and post it's success I need to execute a proc.
This is already setup using Logic Apps, but sometimes the functions takes more than 2 mins and thus it restarts so we are moving to durable functions.
I have already gone through the [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode) on durable function for python, and it is working as expected on local.

I have the trigger
[image]

Output post triggering

[image]
[image]

But when doing the same for my actual durable functions that I needed to create I am getting below errors:
It's not able to recognize the language
[image]

Even after I pass it, it's still not able to figure out the Azure Storage connection
[image]

PS: I have created a temp storage in azure and using the same in both.

EDIT[1]:

**Function Activity**

```
def main(url: str) -> str:
    """Trigger the function url"""
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code in (200, 201):
        return True
    return False
```

**Function Orchestrator**

```
def orchestrator_function(context: DurableOrchestrationContext):
    FUNC_NAMES = os.environ['TBL_FUNCTIONS']

    tasks = []
    for name in FUNC_NAMES:
        tasks.append(context.call_activity('CWFunctionActivity', os.environ[name]))

    results = yield context.task_all(tasks)
    if all(results):
        result = yield context.call_activity('CWFunctionActivity', os.environ['FORECAST_DATASET_PROC'])
    else:
        result = "Check the function execution logs"

    return result
```

**Function HTTP Starter**

```
async def main(req: HttpRequest, starter: str) -> HttpResponse:
    client = DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

**local.settings.json**

```
    {
        "IsEncrypted": false,
          "Values": {
            "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storage_connection_string",
            "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
            "TBL_FUNCTIONS": "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']",
            /*
            "TBL_FUNCTIONS": [
              "TBL_CHARGE_CODES",
              "TBL_EXPENSES",
              "TBL_MEMBERS",
              "TBL_PROJECTS",
              "TBL_PROJECT_TICKETS",
              "TBL_TIME_ENTRIES"
            ],
        */
        "TBL_CHARGE_CODES" : "corresponding_http_url",
        "TBL_EXPENSES": "corresponding_http_url",
        "TBL_MEMBERS" : "corresponding_http_url",
        "TBL_PROJECTS": "corresponding_http_url",
        "TBL_PROJECT_TICKETS": "corresponding_http_url",
        "TBL_TIME_ENTRIES": "corresponding_http_url"
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your durable function code and local setting file's code

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin have added the required info

Comment: please share your Durable function HTTP start code where you are calling your orchestrator function

Comment: Can you please set the value of "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I have already tried that before creating an Azure Storage. It too worked only for the Hello Orchestrator function.

Comment: please share your Durable function HTTP start code where you are calling your orchestrator function

Comment: In the **Function Orchestrator** Code, Add this line `storage_connection = context._binding_data.get('connectionName', None)` before `FUNC_NAMES` line of code

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I've added it as well

Comment: @HarikaReddy can you also tell where to use this storage_connection object?

Comment: In the function orchestrator code, after 1st line

Comment: @HarikaReddy can you confirm how it would help? I am not sure how assigning a value to storage_connection(I guess not a random variable, but also not an object) would help here. Can you please add more context.

Comment: Have you checked adding the line and testing it

Comment: @HarikaReddy I still get the same error, even after the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried the same in my environment with your code, I got the same error.

This seems to be due to the configuration of environment variables in `local.settings.json`.

- Thanks @[Umair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526422/19991670) for the suggestion.

**Resolution:**

I have modified the code in `local.settings.json` as below and it worked.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_CHARGE_CODES" : "corresponding_http_url",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_EXPENSES": "corresponding_http_url",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_MEMBERS" : "corresponding_http_url",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_PROJECTS": "corresponding_http_url",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_PROJECT_TICKETS": "corresponding_http_url",
    "TBL_FUNCTIONS:[0]:TBL_TIME_ENTRIES": "corresponding_http_url"
    }         
}
```

- Could run the function successfully:

[image]

**References:**

[How to set an array value in local.settings.json file in azure functions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025999/how-to-set-an-array-value-in-local-settings-json-file-in-azure-functions)

Comment: Thanks @pravallika. I guess this is because Application settings under function app allows only string - no lists/arrays. The another way is to convert list to string and parsed it in the code.